# Написание шифра Виженера

Tags: c, алгоритм

Пишу шифр Виженера. Не подскажете, где я неточно сформулировал условие?

```
#include <stdio.h> // Стандартная библиотека
#include <cs50.h> // Библиотека для функции get_string и типа переменной string
#include <stdlib.h> // Библиотека для функции atoi
#include <string.h> // Библиотека для функции strlen
#include <ctype.h> // Библиотека для функций isaplha, islower, isupper

int formula(int text_symbol, string key, int key_lenght); // Указываю прототип сделанной позднее функции, чтобы компилятор понял, что она существует.
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) // Вывожу на экран текст с ошибкой, если указано больше или меньше двух аргументов. Изначально название - отдельный аргумент, его всегда нужно учитывать.
    {
        printf("Введите только один аргумент! \n");
        return 1; // return 1 - демонстрация того, что функция сработала не так, как ожидалось изначально.
    }

    else
    printf("Вы ввели правильное значение!\n"); // Демонстрация правильного ввода числа пользователем

    string text = get_string("Введите шифруемый текст: "); // Просим пользователя ввести текст и сохраняем этот текст в переменной под названием text c типом string (строка, массив символов)
    int text_lenght = strlen(text); // Вводим переменную, обозначающую длину текста (text). Сохраняем в неё данные при помощи функции strlen.

    string key = argv[1]; // Сохраняем в переменной key c типом string введённый буквенный ключ от второго аргумента (первый, 0, всегда является названием).
    int key_lenght = strlen(key); // Сохраняем в переменной key_lenght длину ключа, которую мы можем посчитать, так как ранее сохранили ключ в переменной key.

    for (int i = 0; i < text_lenght; i++)
    {
        text[i] = formula(text[i], key, key_lenght);
    }

    printf("%s\n", text); // Вывожу зашифрованный текст на экран. Тип плейсхолдера s (string) автоматически конвертирует все элемента массива text из числовых (int) в символьные (char) по таблице значений ASCII
    return 0; // Правильное завершение программы.
}



int formula(int text_symbol, string key, int key_lenght) /** Задаю функцию formula для рассчёта значений шифруемого текста. Возвращаемое значение будет числовым, так как результатом функции будет ASCII-значение зашифрованного символа.
                                                             Для работоспособности функции вызываем каждый вводимый символ не как char, а как int, получая его цифровое значение в таблице ASCII **/
{
    for (int j = 0; j < key_lenght; j++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text_symbol)) // Задаю условие, при котором мы шифруем только символы из английского алфавита. Проверяем, входит ли символ symbol в этот диапазон.
        {
            if (isupper(text_symbol)) // Задаю условие, при котором мы шифруем только ЗАГЛАВНЫЕ символы из английского алфавита. Проверяем, входит ли символ symbol в этот диапазон.
            {
              text_symbol = (text_symbol - 65 + (int)key[j]) % 26 + 65; /** Вычисляем значение зашифрованного символа symbol_key в таблице ASCII. Для этого делаем следующие шаги:

                                                                1) Переводим ASCII-значение шифруемого символа в алфавитное, вычитая 65 (по таблице ASCII будет 0).
                                                                2) Прибавляем числовое значение ключа
                                                                3) Считаем модуль -  остаток от деления получившегося числа на 26 (число английских букв алфавита и для высокого, и для низкого регистра)
                                                                4) Прибавляем 65, чтобы вернуть получившееся число в таблицу ASCII **/

              return text_symbol; // Результат функции - ASCII-значение зашифроваанного символа.
            }
            else if (islower(text_symbol)) // Задаю условие, при котором мы шифруем только СТРОЧНЫЕ символы из английского алфавита. Проверяем, входит ли символ symbol в этот диапазон.
            {
              text_symbol = (text_symbol - 97 + (int)key[j]) % 26 + 97; /** Вычисляем значение зашифрованного символа symbol_key в таблице ASCII. Для этого делаем следующие шаги:

                                                                1) Переводим ASCII-значение шифруемого символа в алфавитное, вычитая 97 (по таблице ASCII будет 0).
                                                                2) Прибавляем числовое значение ключа
                                                                3) Считаем модуль -  остаток от деления получившегося числа на 26 (число английских букв алфавита и для высокого, и для низкого регистра)
                                                                4) Прибавляем 97, чтобы вернуть получившееся число в таблицу ASCII **/

              return text_symbol; // Результат функции - ASCII-значение зашифрованного символа.
            }
        }
        else
        return text_symbol; // Если символ symbol не входит в английский алфавит, возвращаем его в первоначальном виде, но в числовом значении, так как у функции formula указан тип вывода данных int
    }
    return text_symbol;
}
```

Comment: Честно говоря, использование типа `string` только сбивает с толку... Так в чем именно проблема? Что не работает/работает не так?

Comment: Уточните, с чем именно проблема? О каком условии идет речь?

Comment: Условие было, что при использовании ключевого слова в шифре Виженера буква смещается в системе ASCII на столько позиций, скольким равно ASCII-значение применяемой к конкретной букве конкретной буквы ключа. В таком варианте код менял только первую букву.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шифр Виженера подразумевает, что необходимо сдвигать каждую букву исходного сообщения на соответствующую ключу букву. Первая буква сообщения смещается на первую букву ключа, вторая буква сообщения смещается на вторую букву ключа и тд. Если ключ меньше, то необходимо его циклически повторять до конца сообщения.

Теперь по коду:
Пусть ваша функция formula должна рассчитывать каждую зашифрованную букву на основе исходного текста + ключа + номера буквы в ключе. Возвращать эта функция будет зашифрованную букву. Буду отталкиваться от этой функциональности

Не понятно какую цель вы преследовали, когда написали цикл:

```
for (int j = 0; j < key_lenght; j++)
{
    ...
    return text_symbol;
}
```

При первой итерации цикла(j == 0) у вас произойдет выход из функции, тк на всех if у вас стоят return-ы. Смысл цикла?

По правде говоря, он тут и не нужен. 
Мой вариант:

```
//text_symbol - номер входного символа
//offset - смещение этого символа
int formula(int text_symbol, int offset) 
{
    if (isalpha(text_symbol)) 
    {
        if (isupper(text_symbol)) 
        {
            text_symbol = (text_symbol - 65 + offset) % 26 + 65; 

            return text_symbol; 
        }
        else if (islower(text_symbol)) 
        {
            text_symbol = (text_symbol - 97 + offset) % 26 + 97; 
            return text_symbol; 
        }
    }
    //если число
    return text_symbol; 
}
```

Соответственно этот цикл в main

```
    for (int i = 0; i < text_lenght; i++)
    {
        text[i] = formula(text[i], key, key_lenght);
    }
```

Будет таким:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < text_lenght; i++)
    {
        text[i] = formula(text[i], key[i % key_lenght]);
    }
```

благодаря выражению i % key_lenght мы никогда не выйдем за границу key_length.

Comment: Была проблема с корректным использованием модуля, не додумался, как зациклить использование ключевого слова и подумал, что нужно через цикл for. Условие сформулировал неправильно, так как без указания return symbol выдавало ошибку c non-void function. C тем, как вы расписали, я понял, что формула будет такая же, как и у Цезаря, надо было изменить входные данные. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: Поправка: в исходнике для Цезаря нужно всё же поменять одну штуку. Так как мы считываем символ ключа как число в таблице ASCII, от него тоже нужно отнять 97, чтобы перевести в алфавитный счёт. По условию нужен ключ только со строчными буквами, поэтому 65 не нужно.

Comment: Осталась одна проблема. Нужно, чтобы ключ игнорировал символы, которые не алфавитные, чтобы счёт в нём не увеличивался на 1 каждый раз, когда такой символ встречаем. 

То есть, в текущем виде функция работает так:

meet me at the park
baconbaconbaconb

А нужно, чтобы работала так:

meet me at the park
baco nb ba con baco

Не подскажете, как сделать так, чтобы ключевое слово игнорировало неалфавитные символы и чтобы счётчик в нём при попадании на текстовый неалфавитный символ не менялся?

Comment: Первая мысль - вынести проверку isalpha из функции. Если буква - заходим в функцию и смещаем на offset. Если не буква - пропускаем.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. В главной функции в условии for ввёл второй счётчик j для второй строки по ключевому слову и при несовпадении с условием isalpha у этого счётчика поставил отнимание j--, чтобы неалфавитный символ игнорировался.